# Why do I encountered AttributeError: 'WordListCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'word' in python?

Tags: python, lemmatization

Below is a method that I have tried coding out. However, in line 3 of the codes it said there is an attribute error and that 'WordListCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'word' in python. Please do help me take a look at the below codes :((

```
'''step 3. conduct preprocessing steps'''

# setting up the resources for the preprocessing steps
stop = set(stopwords.word('english'))
exclude = set(string.punctuation)
lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()

def clean(doc):
    stop_free = ''.join([i for i in doc.lower().split() if i not in stop])
    punc_free = ''.join([ch for ch in stop_free if ch not in exclude])
    normalized = ''.join(wn.lemma.lemmatize(word) for word in punc_free.split())
    return normalized
    doc_clean = [clean(doc).split() for doc in corpus]
    '''step 4. prepare word representation'''
    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(doc_clean)
    doc_term_matrix = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in doc_clean]
    '''step 5. create lda model'''
    topic_num = 5
    word_num = 5
    Lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel
    ldamodel = Lda(doc_term_matrix, num_topics=topic_num, id2word=dictionary, passes=20)
    pprint(ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=topic_num, num_words=word_num))
```

This is the trace back after running the codes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/topicmodel/topicmodel.py", line 41, in <module>
    stop = set(stopwords.word('english'))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 119, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self, attr)
AttributeError: 'WordListCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'word'
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation and show the full traceback.

Comment: @roganjosh I have fixed it already please do take a look at my codes, thanks! :(

Comment: It's a typo. It should be `stopwords.words('english')`. Notice the plural `words`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo. The method you should be calling is `stopwords.words()`. Change that:

```
stop = set(stopwords.word('english'))
```

into

```
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

and that should fix this issue.

More information on the NLTK documentation page: 
https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.html?highlight=corpus#module-nltk.corpus